# Importing an html file in basic TypeScript application

Tags: html, typescript, import

### The Problem

I want to import an html template into TypeScript as a string.

Instead I get: error TS2307: Cannot find module '../../html-templates/template.html' or its corresponding type declarations.

---

### My Config

**Folder structure:**

```
Application
|---- html-templates
|   |----template.html
|
|---- ts (the TypeScript root)
    |---- node-modules
    |    |---- *mocha, chai, and all of my required packages live here*
    |
    |---- tests
    |    |---- test.ts
    |    
    |---- html.d.ts
    |---- package.json
    |---- tsconfig.json
```

---

**test.ts**

```
import template from '../../html-templates/template.html';
...
```

---

**html.d.ts**

```
declare module '*.html'
{
    const value: string;
    export default value;
}
```

---

**tsconfig.json**
I'm also open to using module: "commonjs"

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
       "target": "es2017",
       "module": "es2015",
       "moduleResolution": "node",
       "resolveJsonModule": true,
       "esModuleInterop": true,
       "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
       "strict": true,
       "skipLibCheck": true                                 
  }
}
```

---

**template.html** is just an html file with placeholders.

---

### What I've tried.

This [website](https://medium.com/@sampsonjoliver/importing-html-files-from-typescript-bd1c50909992) has some ideas that I've tried but it just doesn't seem to work but I have no trouble importing other files so I think the big problem is finding the type declarations. I have no idea why it can't find them in my html.d.ts file or if that is truly the issue. I've tried the es2015 and common js versions.

I've read descriptions that recommend importing large libraries to help but that seems unnecessary for the simple task of reading in a file as a string. This is a small project and I don't want too much bloat.

I've tried: `let template: string = require('../../html-templates/template.html');` Which will find and read in the file but it tries to parse it and freaks out when it sees the file starts with a '<'.

I'm sure I could just read the file using something like `let template: string= readFileSync('../../html-templates/template.html', 'utf-8');` Maybe that is ok but I like the import semantics more.

Obviously I could just copy the html template into the ts file but that is disgusting and I'd really like to avoid this.

I'm new to the TypeScript world and it seems like this seemingly simple task is absurdly difficult. Help me understand. I'm guessing I'm unknowingly making some sort of assumptions that just are not so.